# Handle settings in a webapp

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am making a webapplication, for handling tickets at school prom.
I want to make a page where users(admins) can edit the settings of this webapp.
What system should I use to store these settings. I think there should be a better way than storing it all in a mysql database or a *.txt file

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: ini files are not too bad for storing settings. They can be access by using the parse_ini_file PHP function

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: @micb Thanks, i will have a look

Comment: @oGeez I am merely expecting there to be a better way than accessing a mysql database everytime a page is loaded to check the settings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please prefer them storing into the database only as there will be a single table for the settings and will not take much load and in real life case the settings of any system are not changed frequently but they are changed rarely.

Better keep them in DB only.

Answer (score 2):

well nothing better then storing them in db, but if you fetch them again and again from db then it'll be an issue, so you can store them in memcache sort of datastore for speedy access.

but do store them in db its just simple.

Comment: Is there not a certain settings file like .config or .settings?

Comment: well there is, but you shouldn't write to these files again and again, not atleast from some web form, you should use them for static settings only.

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports parsing of [`ini` files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) that are made for specifically this requirement.

[Taken from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file):

> The INI file format is an informal standard for configuration files for some platforms or software. INI files are simple text files with a basic structure composed of "sections" and "properties".

Basically, you can pass this file to PHP, parse it, and you'll get a nice associative array containing all of the options set in the file.

Editing the options can be as simple as connecting via FTP and modifying the file, but you could always create a UI or sorts to modify settings and then save the options back into the file.

Comment: Can i then also edit these from a web form, or is a mysql table then a better option?

Comment: No - you can't edit the file directly just like you can't edit a database's contents directly. You'll need another method of saving the details back to the file (just as you needed something to read from the file).